# sqlite error near '''' syntax error data input

Tags: syntax, sqlite, insert-into

I am using sqlite3 and trying to put data into my database.

```
CREATE TABLE CLUB(
cl_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
dtm_opricht TEXT                    NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE STADION(
sta_id      INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
capaciteit  INT                 NOT NULL,
dtm_bouw    TEXT                    NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE TECHNISCHDIRECTEUR(
td_id       INT     PRIMARY KEY     NOT NULL,
cl_id       INT     REFERENCES CLUB(cl_id),
naam        TEXT                    NOT NULL,
adres       VARCHAR(200)                NOT NULL,
salaris     REAL                    NOT NULL,
nationaliteit   TEXT                    NOT NULL,
geslacht    TEXT                    NOT NULL,
dtm_geboorte    TEXT                    NOT NULL
);
```

Everything was going fine with putting in data for the first 2 tables.

```
insert into CLUB values(101, 'Ajax', 'Amsterdamstraat 1', '05-01-1916');
insert into STADION values(201, 101, 'ArenA', 'Arenaweg 10', 50000, '05-03-1990');
```

However when I tried to put data into my 3rd table it gave me a syntax error near "301".

```
insert into TECHNISCHDIRECTEUR(301, 101, 'Michael Kinsbergen', 'Kalverstraat 18', 120000.13, 
 'Nederlands', 'Man', '03-09-1960');
```

What could it be?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the keyword `values`:

```
insert into TECHNISCHDIRECTEUR values(301,...
```